# Snow Leopard and can not install pg because of a corrupt libssl.0.9.8.dylib file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rubygems, installation

I try to install the pg gem with `gem install pg` and it returns :

```
gcc -dynamic -bundle -o pg_ext.bundle pg.o pg_connection.o pg_result.o -L. -L/Users/macuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib -L. -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.2/lib -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -Wl,-flat_namespace  -lruby.1.9.1 -lpq  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc 
ld: in /usr/local/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib, missing required architecture x86_64 in file
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [pg_ext.bundle] Error 1
```

I've tried this :

Currently, I believe there are three different version of postgres on my mac. One of them was a one-click installer, and the others were installed with Brew. Maybe this is the problem?

I install the gem with this :

```
export CONFIGURE_ARGS="with-pg-include=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.3/include"
```

Then again with the newer version :

```
export CONFIGURE_ARGS="with-pg-include=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.2/include"
```

Same error.

Then I tried using  ARCHFLAGS :

```
env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg
```

Still the same error. Not sure what to do.. I also use RVM. Maybe that is a cause?

Where can I find just a newer version of this file? `libssl.0.9.8.dylib`

Thanks~

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly recommend getting rid of the multiple installations and going with just the EnterpriseDB packaged installer.[1](http://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads) And yes, it seems likely that this is the source of your problems. You're going to have other problems working on a box with a bunch of random install junk all over it.